# overlay with scrollbar on main page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

have one div with position absolute. when someone clicks a button in div1, another div div2 with position fixed should scroll up over the first div. Because I do not want two scroll bars to show up (from the first and second div) I remove the scroll bars on the first div (by adding overflow: hidden to the first div) and have the second div scroll up. However, this causes them page to jump. How can I fix this in jquery?

Here's the jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/gkdoefnx/1/

Jquery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button").on('click', function() {
    $('body').addClass('no-scroll');
    setTimeout(function () {
      $('.bottom').addClass("stuck");
      $('.bottom').one('webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function() {
        $('.top').addClass('hide');
      }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this), 1);
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
.npwfu-bottom {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #e8ebed;
    min-height: 100vh;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 250;
    overflow: auto;
    top: 100vh;
    min-width: 1024px;
}
.stuck{
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Notice that when you click on "Click me" in the jsfiddle above, I remove the scroll bar on the page, but there is a jump as the div2 scrolls up.

Comment: Please add a demo link so we can see what you've got so far.

Comment: updated see question